# I can't turn wi-fi on Visual Studio Android Emulator

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, hyper-v

Recently I've been assigned to design a mobile application for my company. I made some research and started using Xamarin Forms to do this. Everything works fine... except when I try to deploy it on Android Emulator.
For some reason, it can't detect network connectivity, which is critical to my application.
[It's trying to turn on wi-fi forever on every device.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTbCL.jpg)

When I opened my Hyper-V configuration, I noticed that I have only one virtual switch - Windows Phone Emulator Internal. When I tried to add external switch with my  and after that new device with my network adapter, not only it doesn't help at all (still the same problem), it also messed with my network connectivity generally and even adapter drivers, resulting after 15 minutes interval Blue Screen with error bcmwl63a.sys every time, so I needed to reinstall drivers.

My coworker said that he installed default settings and he could run android emulator with no problem and had network connection too. He don't have idea what is wrong and we use the same hardware.

My network adapter is Dell Wireless 1560 802.11ac.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Hyper-V Virtual Switch Manager, create a new external virtual switch connected to the hardware adapter (the one with a physical connection, call it Ethernet1). I'll call the virtual switch "Ethernet1 Virtual Switch". Wait for network stack to get rebuilt and reconnect.
2. Right-click on your little network icon in the activity area of the task bar.

3 Go to Open Network and Sharing Center -> Change Adapter Settings

4. Select the newly created Hyper-V Virtual Switch (name looks like vEthernet (Ethernet1 Virtual Switch)
5. Hold the control key and multi-select the disconnected physical adapter (I'll call it Ethernet2)
6. Right-click on either of the two selected items and select Bridge Connections to bridge the virtual switch and the disconnected hardware adapter. Wait for network stack to get rebuilt and reconnect.
7. Select Ethernet2, then right-click and select Remove from Bridge, to remove Ethernet2 from the bridge (this leaves the bridge connected only to the virtual switch)
8. Go back to Hyper-V manager, select the Android emulator VM, click Settings in the lower right-hand pane.
9. Select Add Hardware at the left, select Network Adapter at the right, and click Add.
10. From the Virtual Switch: dropdown on the right, select "Ethernet1 Virtual Switch"
11. Click Apply or OK to save the change.